# В чем суть баз данных в докере?

Tags: база-данных, docker

Я немного не понимаю суть того же `Postgresql` в докере. Сейчас это популярно да и в общем то проект на микросервисах возник. И вот столкнулся с таким понятием.

Чтобы ее нормально хранить, я так понимаю, придется при каждом выключении контейнера обязательно сохранять текущий `state` контейнера.
Но это же не удобно с точки зрения надежности. Контейнер упадет, а вместе с ним и куча данных.

Не могли бы просветить в чем вообще суть баз данных в контейнерах?

Comment: Возможно я чего-то не понимаю, но что мешает поместить базу данных в volume и не трогать state?

Comment: @andreymal, это возможно мое фундаментальное непонимание контейнера, но тогда в чем суть самого контейнера?)

Comment: В том, чтобы программы жили в контролируемой изолированной предсказуемой среде и чтобы было проще запускать-останавливать эти программы (очень актуально для облаков). А хранить изменяемые данные внутри контейнера не нужно, для этого есть volume

Comment: @andreymal, хм. Спасибо я понял

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> в чем вообще суть баз данных в контейнерах?

тут стоит немного уточнить: следует разделять две сущности — базу данных как файл (или набор файлов) и процесс(-ы), выполняющий функцию системы управления базой данных.

в отношении «докеризации» процессов субд, думаю, вопросов нет: тут ровно все те же преимущества (и недостатки), как и для любых других «докеризуемых» процессов.

а вот базу данных, т.е. файлы, её содержащие, для того, чтобы они могли «пережить» пересоздание контейнера с субд, имеет смысл держать отдельно, не в составе этого контейнера:

- либо [в каталоге хост-системы](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/);
- либо с помощью [«механизма» volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#create-and-manage-volumes).

> Чтобы ее нормально хранить, я так понимаю, придется при каждом выключении контейнера обязательно сохранять текущий `state` контейнера. Но это же не удобно с точки зрения надежности. Контейнер упадет, а вместе с ним и куча данных.

когда вы командуете программе *docker* остановить контейнер (по сути — процесс (с его потомками), выполняющийся в изолированном окружении), например, [командой `stop`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/), вы можете указать с помощью опции `-t время`, сколько времени (в секундах, по умолчанию 10) программа будет ожидать завершения процесса:

```
$ docker stop -t время имя-контейнера
```

основному процессу  будет отправлен сигнал `SIGTERM`, и лишь по истечении указанного (или умолчального) интервала времени, если процесс так и не завершился самостоятельно — `SIGKILL`.

эта пауза как раз и служит для того, чтобы процесс успел корректно завершить работу — сохранил данные, закрыл файлы и т.д. и т.п.